# Pyspark - compute min after group by ignoring null values

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to group a dataset and to compute for each group the min of a variable, ignoring the null values. For instance:

```
NAME   | COUNTRY | AGE
Marc   | France  | 20
Anne   | France  | null
Claire | France  | 18
Harry  | USA     | 20
David  | USA     | null
George | USA     | 28
```

If I compute

```
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F
    min_values = data.groupBy("COUNTRY").agg(F.min("AGE").alias("MIN_AGE"))
```

I obtain

```
   COUNTRY | MIN_AGE
   France    null
   USA       null
```

Instead of

```
   COUNTRY | MIN_AGE
   France    18
   USA       20
```

Do you know how to fix it? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can drop na values:

```
min_values = data.na.drop().groupBy("COUNTRY").agg(F.min("AGE").alias("MIN_AGE"))
```

Comment: But what if I need to return other aggregate functions on other columns as well? This will drop the row where there is at least one na in the column?